# If text-indent is set to a percentage value, which width is it using for the calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Another problem related to the rewrite of my [Textarea Line Count plugin](http://mostthingsweb.com/?p=84) (<-- shameless plug)

---

The `text-indent` property of CSS provides white space preceding the first line of text. Possible values include measurements in `px`, `em`, `pt`, etc. but also as a percentage `%`.

So, let's say you specify that your text-area should have: `text-indent: 30%`. But, `30%` of which width is used to perform this calculation? Is it the outer width or the inner width? In other words, are any of the following included in the `width`:

- Border
- Margin
- Padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Border is not included in the calculation, since this technically isn't included in the element's width. Only inner width is measured; no border, padding, margin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

30% the width of the parent. It will always inherit the parent width for percentage.

Padding and border add to the parents width, whereas margin does not, ie

```
#example {width: 200px; padding: 0 5px; border: 1px solid #000;}
```

would be a total width of 212px.

Margin is a positiong tool and only affects what space should be between objects.

Comment: Ok, so it's everything but the margin. Makes sense.

Comment: Yes. Margin is just used for positioning where a div should be. Whereas for example the padding will increase the space between child elements and the border of the div.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the border is not included in the calculation: http://jsfiddle.net/PFq6y/2/ (at least on Chrome)

Comment: Border is included in all broswers, try creating a div with a width of 400px, then inside two child divs of 200px then float them next to each other, they will float as the total is 400px, add a border and they will not as the parent div is 400px and the childs total is 404px, you can test it in all broswers.

Comment: Ok, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PFq6y/3/. As you can see, the first box has a border of width 15px. I've aligned the second box 15px to the right so the actual textareas line up. You can see that the indent is exactly the same, even though the first one has a ridiculous border.

Comment: It must be different for textareas as they are resizeable and have no fixed-width per se, try removing the resize toggle on your text-area.

Comment: @SimpleCoder when you specify width as a percentage, it's a percentage of the parent's **content** size, **not** including the parent's borders or padding. Similarly, the width stipulated for an element is also the **content** width, separate from border and padding. Thus, if you ask for 100% width, and your element has some padding and border, the **overall** width will be greater than 100% of the parent element's width.

Comment: That's the standard "W3C Box Model", and in my opinion it's a giant pain in the neck *most* of the time.

Comment: @Verison1: I'm not sure what you mean by resize toggle, but I've confirmed that Pointy is correct. Border and padding are not included in the calculations. Thank you for your assistance, though.

Comment: @Pointy: Also, if you'd like to make that an answer I'd be happy to accept it :)

Comment: add this to your textarea css: resize:none; this removes the ability for people to use the resize toggle at the bottom right of the textarea, is you should ever need too, look here for more examples http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ Pointy is correct, something which I never knew, but borders and padding are added to width in px, but when using percentages are not it seems, w3c needs to sort that out!